# Position button material design

Tags: html, templates, material-design

How do I place the button in place shown in the figure using material design?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

This is the code on index.html template.

```
<html>
<head>

{% load staticfiles %}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="A front-end template that helps you build fast, modern mobile web apps.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/book_icon.png' %}">

    {% block title %}
        <title>Bookstore</title>
    {% endblock title %}

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Material Design Lite">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ios-desktop.png">

    <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

    <!-- SEO: If your mobile URL is different from the desktop URL, add a canonical link to the desktop page https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/feature-phones -->
    <!--
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/">
    -->

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/material.min.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/styles.css" %}">
    <style>
    #view-source {
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-right: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      z-index: 900;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
      <header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-800">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Bookstore</span>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
            <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search">
              <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            </label>
            <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search" />
              <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Enter your query...</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </header>
      <div class="demo-ribbon"></div>
      <main class="demo-main mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="demo-container mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--hide-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone"></div>
          <div class="demo-content mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--4dp content mdl-color-text--grey-800 mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
            <div class="demo-crumbs">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-shadow--4dp mdl-color--accent" id="add">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">add</i>
                <span class="visuallyhidden">Add</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="demo-crumbs mdl-color-text--grey-500">
              Google &gt; Material Design Lite &gt; How to install MDL
            </div> -->
            <h3>Welcome to the Bookstore</h3>
              <p>Bookstore App example.</p>
            <h3>Bem vindo a Livraria</h3>
              <p>Exemplo de uma aplicação de uma Livraria.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="demo-footer mdl-mini-footer">
          <div class="mdl-mini-footer--left-section">
            <ul class="mdl-mini-footer--link-list">
              <li><a href="#">Bookstore 2015</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </main>
    </div>
    <a href="https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/templates/article/" target="_blank" id="view-source" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--accent mdl-color-text--accent-contrast">Fork on GitHub</a>

    <script src="{% static "js/material.min.js" %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## styles.css

This is the css style for material design.

```
.demo-ribbon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
}

.demo-main {
  margin-top: -35vh;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
}

.demo-header .mdl-layout__header-row {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.demo-container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.demo-content {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 80px 56px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.demo-layout.is-small-screen .demo-content {
  padding: 40px 28px;
}

.demo-content h3 {
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.demo-footer {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.demo-footer .mdl-mini-footer--link-list a {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: You can also try displaying the button as block, setting its margin left to auto, and its margin top to -20px or something. This avoids absolute positioning although it is implemented correctly in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the CSS for the card that holds the FAB, put:

```
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
```

In the CSS for the FAB, put:

```
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: -25px;
```

You might have to make some small adjustments for responsiveness (I'm pretty green at web development), but that'll get you started.